# Posso utilizar qualquer um desses dois para a criação de Hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

Eu estou aprendendo Ruby e estou fazendo dois cursos em paralelo.

No primeiro curso, ensina Hash dessa forma:

```
carro = Hash[nome: 'Civic', marca: 'Honda', cor: 'Vermelho']
```

No segundo curso, ensina Hash dessa forma:

```
# com string
h = { "nome" => "Priscyla", "idade" => 27 }

#com símbolos
h = { :nome => "Priscyla", :idade => 27 }

#pode utilizar desse jeito também se a chave for símbolo
h = { nome: "Priscyla", idade: 27 }
```

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, eu posso utilizar qualquer um desses dois " [ ] " ou " { } " ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Conforme a [documentação](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Hash.html)**, a diferença entre:

```
minha_hash = Hash[...]
```

E:

```
minha_hash = {}
```

É que a segunda é a forma ***literal*** para criar uma `Hash`, ou seja, é apenas um facilitador, não muda em nada o comportamento e não trará "vantagens" ou "desvantagens".

Você também pode criar uma hash vazia usando:

```
minha_hash = Hash.new
```

Que será equivalente a `minha_hash = Hash[]` e `minha_hash = {}`

Outro detalhe é que usando `=>` é a sintaxe **antiga**, já usando `:` é a sintaxe *JSON-like* (estilo JSON), mas só pode usar quando para uma chave `Hash` que é um [**`Symbol`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Symbol.html), em que cada *bareword* se torna um `Symbol`.

Então fazer isso:

```
h = {foo: 0, bar: 1, baz: 2}
```

Será equivalente a fazer isso na sintaxe antiga:

```
h = {:foo => 0, :bar => 1, :baz => 2}
```

E você ainda pode misturar o estilo antigo com o estilo JSON, assim:

```
h = {foo: 0, :bar => 1, 'baz': 2}
```

Você também pode usar strings:

```
h = {'foo': 0, 'bar': 1, 'baz': 2}
```

No entanto, lembrando que em [**`Array`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Array.html) o índice é sempre um [**`Integer`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Integer.html), no `Hash` a chave pode ser **quase** qualquer objeto, então se na **sintaxe estilo JSON**, se tentar usar algo que não for `String` e nem *bareword* (não sei como traduzir isso) irá falhar, causando uma exception `SyntaxError`:

```
# Raises SyntaxError (syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>):
h = {0: 'zero'}
```